# How to validate number of associated objects on create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have the following associatons:

```
A User has_many Order
A Order belongs_to User
```

When creating a User I am able to do it like this:

```
User.create(:orders_attributes => [{:description => 'test'}, {:description => 'test2'}]
```

Because in the User model I have

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :orders
```

I want to be able to limit the number of orders that can be created when creating a User, by doing:

```
validate :max_orders, on: :create

 def max_orders
    errors.add(:base, "error message") if orders.count > 1
  end
```

But I keep seeing that self.orders is 0.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this.

```
validates :orders, length: { is: 1 }, on: :create
```

Comment: Tried that with ``validate :orders, length: { is: 1 }, on: :create`` and it let me create a User with two orders...

Comment: Mistype! I was writting validate instead of validates :) Thanks it works!

Comment: @HommerSmith Good to hear.